# LTspice - "Fatal Error: In Missing node(s)"

Tags: ltspice, boost

I created the boost conveter in LTspice software, but when I try to run the simulation, there was an error message saying:

`Fatal Error: In Missing node(s).`

Can anyone help me out with the problem?

[image: diagram]

[image: SPICE Netlist]

Comment: possible culprits in what you call the booster circuit simulation: if L1 model is ideal, add parallel resistor; C1, do you really mean .028 farads; what is Schottky diode part name/model; Rload may be too small

Comment: Look at the menu item View/SPICE Netlist and post the entire contents of it.

Comment: Besides the advices above, your pulse source has a period of 10 *seconds*; did you mean 10u (*microseconds*)? Also, it's called a boost converter, not a booster.

Comment: Schottky diode part name/model : RBR15BM30A

Comment: pulse source has a period of 10s

Comment: @SachinDalvi Use `@` (`TAB` cycles between the names) to notify people when replying in the comments, otherwise they will never know. Also, this is not very electronics related as much as it is LTspice related. There's a [group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/) dedicated for this.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you wanted to add a node name (`F4`), but you ended up placing a SPICE directive (`S`). That's why the netlist shows `Rload` to be connected between the nodes `N003` and ground, instead of what is seen in the picture, `OUT`. To correct that, delete `OUT`, and `IN` (same thing), and then add the proper naming: either with `F4`, or with the small <kbd>A</kbd> right between the ground and the resistor, in the toolbar. Or from the menu, `Edit > Label Net`.

Not a big deal, but you renamed the MOSFET's designator from `M` to `Q`. That's usually reserved to bipolar transistors, though nothing will happen if you rename it, LTspice takes care of it, anyway (see the `M§Q1` entry in the netlist). Just so you know.